# Visual Studio iOS ripple not reflecting app changes

Tags: apache-cordova

iOS ripple interface does not get updated to the latest interface when rebuilding. Android and Windows does but iOS doesn't reflect changes made. i have cleaned both solution and project, deleted bld folder etc, nothing seems to make iOS ripple reflect app changes.

is there something i'm missing?

Comment: So this has started happening to me to the point where I have delete the platforms/ios and platforms/android folders every time I want to see the change. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue with Android. In order to get it working again, I did the same things you mentioned above and also, in the configuration manager, I set the platform to Android and confirmed that Deploy checkbox is selected for the platform.

Answer (score 0):

what i did to get it to work was to go to my root projects and delete the ios folder in the platform folder. that forced apache cordova to rebuild and it showed me the latest app update